# Why should we copy an ArrayList in some recursive alogrithms?

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist

http://oj.leetcode.com/problems/subsets-ii/

Given a collection of integers that might contain duplicates, S, return all possible subsets.

Note:

```
* Elements in a subset must be in non-descending order.
* The solution set must not contain duplicate subsets.
```

For example,
If S = [1,2,2], a solution is:

```
[
  [2],
  [1],
  [1,2,2],
  [2,2],
  [1,2],
  []
]
```

The answer is:

```
public class Solution {
   public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> subsetsWithDup(int[] num) {
       ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ans = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
       ArrayList<Integer> tmp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       Arrays.sort(num);
       sub(num, 0, tmp, ans);
       return ans;        
   }

   public void sub(int[] num, int k, ArrayList<Integer> tmp, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ans) {
       ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(tmp);            
       ans.add(arr);       

       for (int i = k; i < num.length; i++) {
           if (i != k && num[i] == num[i-1]) continue;

           tmp.add(num[i]);
           sub(num, i+1, tmp, ans);
           tmp.remove(tmp.size()-1);
       }
   }
}
```

I don't know why

```
 ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(tmp);            
 ans.add(arr);
```

But not directly:

```
 ans.add(tmp);
```

Comment: Did you try what you think it should be and checked what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to print out the results, since you remove any element you added after the recursive call, `tmp` should look exactly the same at both the start and the end of the function, so it shouldn't make any difference (your way would be preferred as it doesn't copy the `ArrayList` at each step).

But the problem comes in when you add the results to `ans`.

If you use your way, there would only be a single `ArrayList` floating around - you'd just be adding it to `ans` multiple times.

Note that adding it to `ans` doesn't actually create a copy of it, it just adds a reference to the `ArrayList` to `ans`. So changing the original after it's been added also changes that element of `ans`.

[Live demo showing the correct result by printing them out and the incorrect results in the returned array](http://ideone.com/i2DLfx).

Answer (score 2):

Directly adding it will make arr contain/be the same `ArrayList` instance as tmp.  Down in your loop, when you are altering tmp, you would also be altering arr, which isn't your desired procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Reason for not using

```
 ans.add(tmp);
```

Since tmp is a method argument, so java passes a reference to the ArrayList by value.
So `tmp` actually a reference to a List, not a List.

So you need to create an ArrayList object with and add that object to `ans`

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(tmp);            
ans.add(arr);
```

If you use `ans.add(tmp)`, then the arrayList which tmp points to will be added to ans, and if any modifications are made later in the code to `tmp`, then the contents of the element which you added to `ans` will also change, **since both will point to same memory block**.